# Question's tags, last edit, and author's badge are inside of a <code> element

Tags: bug, status-completed

The issue occurs in this question:

[linked list in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982388/linked-list)

It is occurring for me in Chrome (Mac) and Safari (Mac), but it's not occurring in Android 2.1's native browser. Chrome and Safari both use [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).

[image: Issue shown in Chrome (notice the fixed width font style)]

Comment: Where are you seeing this? The question? An answer? They all look fine to me. Maybe your page didn't finish loading, and your browser made a best-guess attempt at rendering it with the information it had?

Comment: @populardemand It's occurring in the question. The question's tags, last edit, and author's badge all use a fixed-width font.

Comment: I'm on a different computer and Internet connection now, and it's still no-repro.

Comment: IIRC, this is due to an old bug and editing the post (even adding just a space) will rerender and fix it. @pop I can repro on Safari.

Comment: I can see the same issue on Firefox 4 (Minefield) on Windows 7.

Comment: Ah, I thought the OP was reporting a similar but different bug until the screenshot went up. Glad it's sorted, at any rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigation of the source and some attempts to reproduce the issue here (see the edit history of this answer), I found that the code was cut-off somewhere in the middle of the bottom section.

Finding no obvious reason why, I made a small edit under the assumption that the database contained some stale formatted version, and that the random cut-off of the post led to a missing close `<code>` tag. It turns out my edit did, in fact resolve the issue.

On a side note -- and possibly related -- the title wasn't the minimum required 15 characters, so I added a few so that I could actually submit my edit.

Comment: correct, this was an old rare bug in the server-side markdown renderer.. entering a no-op edit forces it to re-render and fixes it.